# Test kong custom plugin occurred dns server error: 3 name error

Tags: kong, openresty

When doing a kong plugin test with the following code, I encountered dns server error.
The test case is simple to do a get request. The upstream service is a service deployed in an inner k8s cluster. I'm using `kong-vagrant` to do the test on my windows 10 PC.

```
local helpers = require "spec.helpers"
local pl_pretty = require "pl.pretty"

local PLUGIN_NAME = "myplugin"

for _, strategy in helpers.each_strategy({"postgres"}) do
  describe(PLUGIN_NAME .. ": (access) [#" .. strategy .. "]", function()
  local client

  lazy_setup(function()

    local bp = helpers.get_db_utils(strategy, nil, { PLUGIN_NAME })

    local service = bp.services:insert {
      name     = "service-mockbin",
      url      = "http://pabc-doc.k8s.io:30283/docs/",
    }

    --  local service = bp.services:insert {
    --   name     = "service-mockbin",
    --   url      = "https://mockbin.com/request",
    -- }
    
    local route1 = bp.routes:insert({
      paths = { "/docs" },
      service   = service
    })
    
    -- add the plugin to test to the route we created
    bp.plugins:insert {
      name = PLUGIN_NAME,
      route = { id = route1.id },
      config = {},
    }

    -- start kong
    assert(helpers.start_kong({
      -- set the strategy
      database   = strategy,
      -- use the custom test template to create a local mock server
      nginx_conf = "spec/fixtures/custom_nginx.template",
      -- make sure our plugin gets loaded
      plugins = "bundled," .. PLUGIN_NAME,
    }))
  end)

  lazy_teardown(function()
    helpers.stop_kong(nil, true)
  end)

  before_each(function()
    client = helpers.proxy_client()
  end)

  after_each(function()
    if client then client:close() end
  end)

  describe("request", function()
    it("get login", function()
      local r = client:get("/docs")
      pl_pretty.dump(r)
      assert.response(r).has.status(200)

    end)
  end)

  end)
end
```

Error:

```
2020/06/23 12:27:49 [error] 4297#0: *2 [lua] balancer.lua:929: execute(): DNS resolution failed: dns server error: 3 name error. Tried: ["(short)pabc-doc.k8s.io:(na) - cache-miss","pabc-doc.k8s.io:33 - cache-hit/dns server error: 3 name error","pabc-doc.k8s.io:1 - cache-hit/dns server error: 3 name error","pabc-doc.k8s.io:5 - cache-hit/dns server error: 3 name error"], client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /docs HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:9000"
```

If I start a kong service and configure the upstream service, then access it through browser, it works.
And put the following code in the custom plugin, it can get the ip

```
 local ip, port, try_list = toip("pabc-doc.k8s.io", 30283, false)
```

So what else I should set up to make it work while doing test with `busted`.